# sql syntax error check manual

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

i am new to php programming. I always get this error when i run my code

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE service_name = ''' at line 7`

this is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../conn/openconn.php');
if(isset($_POST['butsend'])) {

$servicename = strtoupper($_POST['txtservicename']);
$serviceurl = $_POST['txtserviceurl'];
$id_div = $_POST['select_div'];
$id_unit = $_POST['select_unit'];
$servicedesc = $_POST['txtservicedesc'];
$id = $_SESSION['service_name'];

$updateuser = "UPDATE service SET 
               service_name = '$servicename',
               service_url = '$serviceurl',              
               id_div = '$id_div',
               id_unit = '$id_unit',
               service_desc = '$servicedesc',
               WHERE service_name = '$id'";
    mysql_query($updateuser) or die (mysql_error());

}

?>
```

i have already search all the previous question but due to my limited knowledge in the programming i 
cannot find the solution. sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra comma. Remove it.

```
$updateuser = "UPDATE service SET 
           service_name = '$servicename',
           service_url = '$serviceurl',              
           id_div = '$id_div',
           id_unit = '$id_unit',
           service_desc = '$servicedesc', <-- HERE
           WHERE service_name = '$id'";
```